# Restart potential energy scan in Gaussian with additional scan points

Tags: gaussian, geometry, potential-energy-surface

I have finished a scan of a bond length, but I need to continue the coordinate scan adding more points to the same scan.

I thought of writing a second input file from the last geometry, relaunching the scan updating the redundant coordinates. Is there another way like something scan=(restart)?.

Comment: +1, but good edit @Phil Hasnip ! I was confused in thinking this might be about the SCAN functional :)

Comment: What do u mean by adding more points to the same scan. Do u mean for example you did the scan and the distance became 3.2 A and you want to add more points to this distance to increase or decrease the distance ?

Comment: @Abd-ElazeemMohamed I started a potential energy scan along a bend length. I set up 37 steps of 0.1 Amstrong. I calculated wrong the final distance and I'll need 47 steps. Is there a way to restart the calculation without losing the already 16 steps taken?

Comment: Can you just start the new scan where the last one finished?

Comment: @PhilHasnip ok, but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Andrea,  I agree with @PhilHasnip, I don't think there is another way. You just need to take the last geometry and resubmit again the calculation and don't worry you will not lose any accuracy. At the end, you can extract the data from the two calculations.

Comment: @Abd-ElazeemMohamed it wasn't for the accuracy but for the workflow. If there is no other methods I'll go for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, something like this should work.

```
%oldchk=short_scan.chk
%chk=new_scan.chk
#p opt=modredundant Geom=(Checkpoint,ModRedundant)

0 1 !Or your particular charge/multiplicity

!Your new scan coordinate
```

This should read the last scan step from the prior checkpoint file and then you can start a new scan (or other modredundant coordinate modification) from there. This assumes you are doing a relaxed scan and not using the `scan` keyword to do a rigid scan. I don't know how rigid scans interact with the checkpoint file.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching